# Laravel app is not running in public_html folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i deployed my laravel application to public_html/demo folder. Its working well in this folder but when i moved all my codes to public_html/  folder am getting a blank page, Also am not getting any errors in log/laravel.log, What should i do and why this problem is occurring

Comment: Did you switch your document root to public_html/public? Any errors in your apache/nginx logs?

Comment: Ryt now am running a basic php app in public_html folder its working well and am running laravel app in public_html/demo folder even thats working well. But when i more laravel app to public_html folder its not working @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much of research i found the problem.

The PHP was not loading.

By adding these lines in the .htaccess file it resolves my problem

```
DirectoryIndex index.php login.php index.html
RewriteEngine on

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0):

add .htaccess file in your public html and write this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ demo/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

you should change the root folder using .htaccess like that